# Syntax error, unexpected token ")" when sending mail in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, swiftmailer, symfony-mailer

I know the title seems familiar but hear me out...

My code works locally when I try to send out an invoice via email and the email gets sent. However, I deployed the same code to production on ec2 and got this error;
[image]

My controller looks like this...

```php
public function invoice_send(Request $request, Invoice $invoice)
{
    Mail::to($request->to)->queue(new NewInvoice($invoice, $request));

    return redirect()->route('invoice.show', $invoice);
}
```

The vendor folder is the only thing that is different between production and development servers so I deleted the vendor and run `composer install` again but that didn't solve anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are queueing the email.
It could be that an old version of your code is used for processing the queue. You can have a look at the [Laravel documentation about this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#the-queue-work-command).
Try restarting the queue-worker if configured.

Comment: I don't have a queue configured for this actually. It should work either way.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by downgrading my PHP version from 8.1.8 to 8.0.21.